# TypeError: not a function when using new

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

This below does not raise any error:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {

    this.prototype[name] = func;

};

Function.method('inherits', function (Parent) {

    this.prototype = new Parent(  );
    this.prototype.construct = this;

});


var p = function(){}
var c = function(){}

c.inherits(p)
```

But this below raises "TypeError: _a.inherits is not a function":

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {

    this.prototype[name] = func;

};

Function.method('inherits', function (Parent) {

    this.prototype = new Parent(  );
    this.prototype.construct = this;

});


//var p = function(){}
//var c = function(){}

function a(){}
function b(){}

_a = new a();
_b = new b();

_a.inherits(_b)
```

From what I read, the return value of new is a function. It has to be a function because it has a prototype property that can be used and assigned and a constructor property pointing to itself. In the prototype lookup algorithm, it should discover "inherits" in Function.prototype before it passes through Object.prototype. No?

Comment: Why do you think the `inherits` method exists on `kid`?

Comment: @user2357112 because kid is a function, and inherits was created on Function.prototype, and the prototype lookup algorithm should pass through Function.prototype before it hits Object.prototype.

Comment: @user2357112 it only fails when using the new keyword. Without the new keyword, no error is thrown. new keyword should return a function, after all only functions have a prototype property and a costructor pointing to the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, The return value of new is not a function.

When a function is called with new keyword, a new object is created and assigned to "this" in the constructor function and is returned.

Also the object that gets created doesnt have a prototype property. As can be confirmed from :

```
 alert(typeof kid); // object
   alert(kid['prototype']); //undefined
   alert(kid['constructor'].prototype); //object
```

As I understand through this constructor function property, the prototype inheritance works.

Comment: So it has a constructor property which points to the function that the object was created in, so you access the prototype property through that function. And therefore, inheritance is established that way.

Answer (score 0):

`kid` is not a function, it is an `object`. You can read up about the `new` keyword here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Here's some usage based on your code:

```
var kid = Child;
kid.inherits(Parent);

var bart = new kid();
bart.say();
```

Comment: Before I accept that kid is an object and not a function, then why does it have access to prototype property? Only functions can use the prototype property.

Comment: You can check result of alert(typeof kid); It returns object and not function.

Comment: @coder yes I can do that and it will return an object. But my question still remains if it is an object and not a function, then why is it able to modify and use the prototype property? To create a prototype chain you have to create a function.

Comment: @JohnMerlino "...then why is it able to modify and use the prototype property". It can't.

Comment: @sahbeewah bart.prototype.name does not return "undefined" in my browser, but something like obj={}; obj.prototype.name would. obj would because it is an object and you cannot modify its protoype property, but you can modify the prototype propetty of a function.

Answer (score 0):

`_a` is not a `function` it's an `object` and you wrote `inherits(Parent)` for js `functions` so
 call it on function and then create new object from inherited `function`.

eg-

```
        b.prototype.y=function(){ //add y to b
        alert("y from b called");
        }
        a.inherits(b);//inherits function b 
        _a = new a();//create obj from a after inheritence
        _a.y();// call method of b
```